# Passing more than one array using bundle

Tags: java, android, arrays, bundle

I am trying to pass 2 double arrays from one activity to the other. However when I try to pass the values from the 2 arrays in the first activity to the arrays in the second activity I get just the values from the first array and its stored in both new arrays.

This is how I use the bundle to send the arrays

```
Bundle bund = new Bundle();
bund.putDoubleArray(endLatitudeStr, endLatitude);
intent.putExtras(bund);
Bundle bund2 = new Bundle();
bund2.putDoubleArray(endLongitudeStr, endLongitude);
intent.putExtras(bund2);        
startActivity(intent);
```

And the on the receiving side I have:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
mXmlRpcUrl = intent.getStringExtra("XmlRpcUrl");
mSessionID = intent.getStringExtra("SessionID");
mGetSavedTripFunc = intent.getStringExtra("GetSavedTripFunc");
Bundle bund = intent.getExtras();
endLatitude = bund.getDoubleArray(endLatitudeStr);
Bundle bund2 = intent.getExtras();
endLongitude = bund2.getDoubleArray(endLongitudeStr);
```

However the result is always just the values from the first array(in this case endLatitude) 
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does your endLatitudeStr equals endLongitudeStr?

Answer (score 2):

Use same bundle object.

```
Bundle bund = new Bundle();
bund.putDoubleArray(endLatitudeStr, endLatitude);
bund.putDoubleArray(endLongitudeStr, endLongitude);
intent.putExtras(bund);        
startActivity(intent);

Intent intent = getIntent();
mXmlRpcUrl = intent.getStringExtra("XmlRpcUrl");
mSessionID = intent.getStringExtra("SessionID");
mGetSavedTripFunc = intent.getStringExtra("GetSavedTripFunc");
Bundle bund = intent.getExtras();
endLatitude = bund.getDoubleArray(endLatitudeStr);
endLongitude = bund.getDoubleArray(endLongitudeStr);
```

Comment: Nope it doesnt work still getting just the values of the first array I send :/

Comment: So probably the problem is elsewhere can you prove us the endLatitudeStr and endLongitudeStr are different strings

Comment: yep they are different strings in each form

Comment: Ok. Are you sure you didn't make a typo somewhere in your code between latitude and longitude ? Because the code given here should work. Can you logcat the two arrays before sending and after receiving and showing they are different before and same after.

Comment: Bundle[{null=[D@413fa430}]

Comment: I am having trouble using logcat but before sending 
bund.putDoubleArray(endLatitudeStr, endLatitude); has a different value from bund.putDoubleArray(endLongitudeStr, endLongitude); and at the end I receive only latitude

Comment: W8 I was wrong I was not receiving the first array. The values form the second array are stored in the arrays of the second form

Comment: if you use only 1 bundle it should work, I can't help more with that.

Answer (score 0):

If i recall correctly you can only use one bundle because if you make another bundle it will replace the previous bundle so what you need to do is put the bund1 and bun2 on the first bundle then retrieve it 
use

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String mystring=bundle.getString("bund1");
String mystring=bundle.getString("bund2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use 2 Bundles? Just use one ...

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putDoubleArray(endLatitudeStr, endLatitude);
bundle.putDoubleArray(endLongitudeStr, endLongitude);
intent.putExtra(bundle);        
startActivity(intent);
```

and ...

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
endLatitude = bundle.getDoubleArray(endLatitudeStr);
endLongitude = bundle.getDoubleArray(endLongitudeStr);
```